# How to use a SipServlet with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, http, sip, sip-servlet

How to use a SipServlet with Spring such as the available on http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071781/java-web-development/sip-programming-for-the-java-developer.html?page=2 ?

I'm using `Spring MVC` to map HTTP requests so for any given function I can use the annotation `@RequestMapping`. **Is there any way to map the requests like spring MVC?**

**To summarize:**
From where can I start to implement a SIP endpoint in my current Spring project that already serves as a HTTP endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Spring MVC` for your `SIP` handling code. Spring's `DispatcherServlet` extends `HTTPServlet`, and does not handle `SIP` calls. You will have to implement `SIPServlet`'s methods yourself and register the servlet properly with the app, either with `sip.xml` or SIP annotations. You still can utilize Spring Framework in your service layer.

Comment: I'm setup a SipServlet but it's not starting. I've tried with sip.xml and with annotations and the init function is not running. Is there any example SipServlet integration with Spring that I can follow?